# Excel Paste Special Values Only

Tags: excel, copy-paste, paste, excel-2016

I am bringing in a column of data from an external spreadsheet into one I developed. Mine has very specific formats applied to ensure formulas work. One of the columns requires data to be formatted as 'Number'.

The source spreadsheet has a column with both 'Number' formatted cells and 'Number stored as text' cells.

When I copy this column and use 'Paste Special - Values Only' I get the same cells with 'Number stored as text'.

I thought that the 'Paste Special - Values Only' was meant to prevent this kind of issue.

Can someone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

1. arrange yourself a service column and fromat it as `"General"`
2. then insert a formulas into this service column like this
       `=value(A1)` where `A1` is the `location of a number` which is stored as text
3. copy the `service colunm` into the `A column` (which is where the number
   is located as text)

the problem should be solved then

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I was hoping that someone could explain why this was happening as I am already able to easily convert to number after the fact by selecting on the range of affected cells (indicated by a green tag at the top left of the cell) and selecting Convert to number...

Comment: the reason for this sort of problem should come from diffrent causes... 1) it may be the source format issue 2) end cell format issue 3) the settings of the local machine (decimal separation symbol) 4) type of the variable used to store the value copied